# Android - Way to remember the details selected

Tags: android, restrictions

I am currently developing an android app to help coaches.

The idea of the game is not to let the players play in the same position twice. I have a `list view` which contains the names of the players. I then select a name and drop it on a position which is a `TextView`.

Is there a way that I can get the app to remember which name was dropped where and not to let that name be dropped there again?

Thanks!

Comment: u can store the position of the player in the shared pref

Comment: you could remove the name from the ListView, after dropping it. So it wouldnt be re-selectable

Comment: I tried to store the position of a player in a shared pref but it doesn't seem to work the way I hoped! 
I also removed the name from the list once used and that worked no problem but I then needed to be able to play that player in another position which couldn't be done. 
Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SharedPrefernces`  to store the value

Check the below link to know about shared preference

[use Shared prefernce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you think it would be possible to maybe do something like an if statement? I've tried a couple but I can't seem to solve it!